# PHPMailer: incomplete href link in mail body

Tags: email, phpmailer

I have an issue but only occurring with Outlook. In Gmail it works.
The url is https://somewebsite/en/account-verification?email=some@email.com&verification_code=some_code

But when you hover over the link in the mail you get only https://somewebsite/en.

when I view the source, the link is:
https://somewebsite/en/account-verification?email=some@email.com&verification_code=some_code

I thought the issue was because of the "&". But that's not the case because when I check to other mails I get like for example Facebook, they have the same and it works.

The link is valid on the website.

The content of the email is the content of an html file which has a  tag

Below you can see my PHPMailer settings

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp-auth.mailprotect.be';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'xxx';
$mail->Password   = 'xxx';
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
$mail->Port       = 465;
//Recipients
$mail->setFrom($from, $from_name);
$mail->addAddress($to);
//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $content;
$mail->send();
```

The headers which I think matter to help:

- MIME-Version: 1.0
- Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

UPDATE: I've added SMTPDebug = 2 to have the logs:

```
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 smtp-auth.mailprotect.be ESMTP - Welcome<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO www.xxx.xx<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp-auth.mailprotect.be250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 52428800250-VRFY250-ETRN250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250-DSN250 CHUNKING<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH LOGIN<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: [credentials hidden]<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: MAIL FROM:&lt;xxxx@xxx.xx&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250 2.1.0 Ok<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: RCPT TO:&lt;xxxx@xxx.xx&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250 2.1.5 Ok<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: DATA<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 354 End data with &lt;CR&gt;&lt;LF&gt;.&lt;CR&gt;&lt;LF&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Date: Fri, 5 Aug 2022 19:22:15 +0200<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: To: xxxx@xxx.xx<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: From: Support &lt;xxxx@xxx.xx&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Subject: Confirm your email address<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Message-ID: &lt;tiPohR4zaO04Mccof0KMXEmdZaylCONxkFoOE9eSHU@www.xxx.xx&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 6.6.3 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: MIME-Version: 1.0<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: <br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: &lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: &lt;html xmlns:v=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml&quot; xmlns:o=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office&quot; lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:    &lt;head&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;title&gt;&lt;/title&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=utf-8&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width,initial-scale=1&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;!--[if mso]&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;xml&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:          &lt;o:OfficeDocumentSettings&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;o:PixelsPerInch&gt;96&lt;/o:PixelsPerInch&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;o:AllowPNG/&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:          &lt;/o:OfficeDocumentSettings&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;/xml&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;![endif]--&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;style&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:          *{box-sizing:border-box}body{margin:0;padding:0}a[x-apple-data-detectors]{color:inherit!important;text-decoration:inherit!important}#MessageViewBody a{color:inherit;text-decoration:none}p{line-height:inherit}.desktop_hide,.desktop_hide table{mso-hide:all;display:none;max-height:0;overflow:hidden}@media (max-width:660px){.desktop_hide table.icons-inner{display:inline-block!important}.icons-inner{text-align:center}.icons-inner td{margin:0 auto}.row-content{width:100%!important}.image_block img.big{width:auto!important}.column .border,.mobile_hide{display:none}table{table-layout:fixed!important}.stack .column{width:100%;display:block}.mobile_hide{min-height:0;max-height:0;max-width:0;overflow:hidden;font-size:0}.desktop_hide,.desktop_hide table{display:table!important;max-height:none!important}}<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;/style&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:    &lt;/head&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:    &lt;body style=&quot;background-color:#f8f8f9;margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;text-size-adjust:none&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;table class=&quot;nl-container&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;background-color:#f8f8f9&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;tbody&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:          &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                &lt;table<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                   class=&quot;row row-3&quot; align=&quot;center&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                   &lt;tbody&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                      &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                         &lt;td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                            &lt;table class=&quot;row-content stack&quot; align=&quot;center&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;background-color:#fff;color:#000;width:640px&quot; width=&quot;640&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                               &lt;tbody&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                  &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                     &lt;td class=&quot;column column-1&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; <br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-weight:400;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;border-top:0;border-right:0;border-bottom:0;border-left:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;table class=&quot;image_block&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;td style=&quot;width:100%;padding-right:0;padding-left:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;div align=&quot;center&quot; style=&quot;line-height:10px&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;a href=&quot;https://xxxxx.xx/en&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; style=&quot;outline:none&quot; tabindex=&quot;-1&quot;&gt;&lt;img class=&quot;big&quot; src=&quot;https://xxxxx.xx/images/emails/mathew-schwartz--bAZGsko_po-unsplash-720.jpg&quot; style=&quot;display:block;height:auto;border:0;width:640px;max-width:100%&quot; width=&quot;640&quot; alt=&quot;Logo Company&quot; title=&quot;Logo Company&quot;&gt;&lt;/a&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;table class=&quot;divider_block&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; <br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;td style=&quot;padding-top:30px&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;div align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;table border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                          &lt;td class=&quot;divider_inner&quot; style=&quot;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;border-top:0 solid #bbb&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#8202;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;table class=&quot;text_block&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; <br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;word-break:break-word&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;td style=&quot;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;padding-top:10px&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;div style=&quot;font-family:Arial,sans-serif&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;div class=&quot;txtTinyMce-wrapper&quot; style=&quot;font-size:12px;font-family:&#039;Helvetica Neue&#039;,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;mso-line-height-alt:14.399999999999999px;color:#555;line-height:1.2&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;p style=&quot;margin:0;font-size:16px;text-align:center&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                          &lt;span style=&quot;font-size:30px;color:#dd204e;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Welcome at Company!&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;/p&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;table class=&quot;text_block&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;word-break:break-word&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;td style=&quot;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:40px;padding-right:40px;padding-top:10px&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;div style=&quot;font-family:sans-serif&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;div class=&quot;txtTinyMce-wrapper&quot; <br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       style=&quot;font-size:12px;font-family:Montserrat,Trebuchet MS,Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans Unicode,Lucida Sans,Tahoma,sans-serif;mso-line-height-alt:18px;color:#555;line-height:1.5&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;p style=&quot;margin:0;font-size:14px;text-align:left;font-family:inherit;mso-line-height-alt:22.5px&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color:#808389;font-size:15px;&quot;&gt;Dear Yannick,&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;br&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;p style=&quot;margin:0;font-size:14px;text-align:left;font-family:inherit;mso-line-height-alt:22.5px&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color:#808389;font-size:15px;&quot;&gt;You registered an account on xxxx.xx, before being able to use your account you need to verify that this is your email address by clicking here:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;div align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                          &lt;!--[if mso]&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                          &lt;v:roundrect xmlns:v=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml&quot; xmlns:w=&quot;urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word&quot; href=&quot;https://xxxxx.xx/en&quot; style=&quot;height:62px;width:209px;v-text-anchor:middle;&quot; arcsize=&quot;57%&quot; stroke=&quot;false&quot; fillcolor=&quot;#dd204e&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                             &lt;w:anchorlock/&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                             &lt;v:textbox inset=&quot;0px,0px,0px,0px&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                                &lt;center style=&quot;color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                                   &lt;![endif]--&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                                   &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.xxx.xx/en/account-verification?email=xxxx@xxx.xx&amp;verification_code=613dbf3699a7cc42bd68f67cf8989992&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot; style=&quot;text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:#ffffff;background-color:#dd204e;border-radius:35px;width:auto;border-top:1px solid #dd204e;font-weight:undefined;border-right:1px solid #dd204e;border-bottom:1px solid #dd204e;border-left:1px solid #dd204e;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;font-family:&#039;Helvetica Neue&#039;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;font-size:16px;display:inline-block;letter-spacing:normal;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-size: 16px; margin: 0; line-height: 2; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 32px;&quot;&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Verify now&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/a&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                                   &lt;!--[if mso]&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                                &lt;/center&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                             &lt;/v:textbox&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                          &lt;/v:roundrect&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                          &lt;![endif]--&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;p style=&quot;margin:0;font-size:14px;text-align:left;font-family:inherit;mso-line-height-alt:22.5px&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;color:#808389;font-size:15px;&quot;&gt;Kind regards,&lt;br&gt;Company Support Team &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;table class=&quot;divider_block&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;td style=&quot;padding-bottom:12px;padding-top:60px&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;div align=&quot;center&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;table border=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; role=&quot;presentation&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; style=&quot;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0&quot;&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                          &lt;td class=&quot;divider_inner&quot; <br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                             style=&quot;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;border-top:0 solid #bbb&quot;&gt;&lt;span&gt;&amp;#8202;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                       &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                    &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                                 &lt;/div&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                              &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                           &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                        &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                     &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                                  &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                               &lt;/tbody&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                            &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                         &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                      &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                   &lt;/tbody&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:                &lt;!-- End --&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:             &lt;/td&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:          &lt;/tr&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;/tbody&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:       &lt;/table&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER:    &lt;/body&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: &lt;/html&gt;<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: <br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: .<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CA5A7C0142<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2022-08-05 17:22:15 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye<br>
```

I've been doing numerous permutations between the values of the following properties: Encoding, CharSet, ContentType, isHtml + Body versus MsgHTML, ...
Comparing mail headers between mails from Facebook and the mail that I'm sending...
Stackoverflow is my last resort before getting cray :p.

Any help will be very valuable.

Thanks!

Comment: I may help to set `SMTPDebug = 2` and look at exactly what's being sent. Also make sure you're using latest PHPMailer.

Comment: @Synchro, Thank you for the quick response! I updated my question with the logs.
I've put all of it to be sure. I only replaced some info by "xxx"

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out why.
in my html template, I have an exception for mso. But in my editor, that exception is greyed out because it's in html comment (<!--). I's also greyed out by Stackoverflow as well ;) So I always overlooked that part

```html
<div align="center">
   <!--[if mso]>
   <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="https://xxx.xx/en" style="height:62px;width:209px;v-text-anchor:middle;" arcsize="57%" stroke="false" fillcolor="#dd204e">
      <w:anchorlock/>
      <v:textbox inset="0px,0px,0px,0px">
         <center style="color:#ffffff; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16px">
            <![endif]-->
            <a href="{confirmation_link}" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;display:inline-block;color:#ffffff;background-color:#dd204e;border-radius:35px;width:auto;border-top:1px solid #dd204e;font-weight:undefined;border-right:1px solid #dd204e;border-bottom:1px solid #dd204e;border-left:1px solid #dd204e;padding-top:15px;padding-bottom:15px;font-family:'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;text-align:center;mso-border-alt:none;word-break:keep-all;"><span style="padding-left:30px;padding-right:30px;font-size:16px;display:inline-block;letter-spacing:normal;"><span style="font-size: 16px; margin: 0; line-height: 2; word-break: break-word; mso-line-height-alt: 32px;"><strong>Verify now</strong></span></span></a>
            <!--[if mso]>
         </center>
      </v:textbox>
   </v:roundrect>
   <![endif]-->
<br><br>
<p style="margin:0;font-size:14px;text-align:left;font-family:inherit;mso-line-height-alt:22.5px"><span style="color:#808389;font-size:15px;">Kind regards,<br>Support Team </span></p>
</div>
```

As you can see there's a [if mso] condition. And in there you will see a static url https://xxx.xx/en. So Instead I just replaced it with the dynamic {confirmation_link} url.